# Monitor file size and export result to csv every minute using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Using PowerShell I would like to monitor the file size of an application error log and write the size every minute for 24 hours to a .csv file. I'm not sure where the problem is in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
$a = dir c:\users\rob\desktop\testharness\TestFile.txt
$a | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileLength -Value Length
$b = $a.FileLength
$MaxSamples = 1440
$SampleInterval = 1
write-host "starting job"
Start-Job {
    Param($jobs, $sample, $interval)
    $jobs
    $sample
    $interval
    Get-Counter $jobs -MaxSamples $sample -SampleInterval $interval |
    Export-Counter -path $home\FileSize.csv -FileFormat CSV -Force
} -Name test -ArgumentList @($b, $MaxSamples, $SampleInterval) 
Wait-Job test | Remove-Job
write-host "job done"
```

Comment: i think your code is incomplete ,can you add the $jobs definition as well.The code sample you give should be minimal and verifiable

Comment: The Get-Counter CMDlet that you are using in the job is made to get performance counters from the local machine (or a remote machine). From my understanding there is not going to be a counter available that will measure the file size of a specific file on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
$LogFile = 'c:\Temp\log.txt'
$Csv = 'c:\Temp\LogFileSize.csv'
$MinsIn24Hours = 1440

"Time,Size" | Out-File $Csv

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MinsIn24Hours; $i++) {

    $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"

    # Get file size and confirt to minutes
    $Size = (Get-Item $LogFile).Length / 1KB

    "$Now,$Size KB" | Out-File $Csv -Append
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Note: Because each iteration takes some time to execute, you might lose a few seconds over the course of 24 hours:

```
Measure-Command{  
    $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"
    $Size = (Get-Item $LogFile).Length / 1KB
    "$Now,$Size KB" | Out-File $Csv -Append
}
```

11 milliseconds * 1440 =
15.84 seconds

Comment: If you want exactly 1440 samples that are in roughly 24 hours that works, or you could take a start time and calculate an end time, then sample until that window expires.